# Decimal to binary conversion output

Tags: c++, c, binary, decimal

What wrong with my code anyone help me plz .It's a decimal to binary conversion . According to my code , the out will be 2 for 10 , 3 for 11 but it output always add the last value at the end like for 3 it shows 1110  , add the previous output . What should I do now ? help me plz ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    long int decimalNumber,quotient;

    int binaryNumber[100],i=0,j;

    printf("Enter any decimal number: ");

    //scanf_s("%ld",&decimalNumber);
    while(scanf_s("%ld",&decimalNumber)==1)
    {

            quotient = decimalNumber;

            while(quotient!=0){
             binaryNumber[i++]= quotient % 2;
             quotient = quotient / 2;
           }

           printf("Equivalent binary value of decimal number %d: ",decimalNumber);

           for(j = i -1 ;j>= 0;j--)
               printf("%d",binaryNumber[j]);
           printf("\n");
           printf("Enter any decimal number: ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialise `i` at the start of every loop

```
while(scanf_s("%ld",&decimalNumber)==1)
{
    i = 0;
```

Without this, you'll append each new number to the end of the last one, repeating until you write beyond the end of `binaryNumber`.